# jquery for each function

Tags: jquery, loops

I have added a show more or less function to a div - this all works fine however now i need to only allow this functionality if a element is over a certain height in this case. there are numerous classes of the same so i need to do the check on each element. although i am having problems getting it to work see code below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".less").hide();
$(".more").each(function() {
        var actualHeight = ($(this).parent().parent().find('.appsList').height());
        if (actualHeight < 150) {
        $(".more").hide();  
        }

                         });

$(".more").click(function() {
        var paragraphHeight = ($(this).parent().parent().find('.appsList').height());
        if (paragraphHeight > 150) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.appsHolderBody').animate({height:(paragraphHeight + 100) });
        $(this).hide('slow');
        $(this).parent().find('.less').show();
        }
        return false;    
                          });

$(".less").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.appsHolderBody').animate({height:190 });             
        $(this).hide('slow');
        $(this).parent().find('.more').show();
        return false;
                          });

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - please note when i am targeting the parent using .parent.parent i know its not pretty but could'nt get it to run using eq(4) for some reason.

so the main problem is with this part of code

```
$(".more").each(function() {
        var actualHeight = ($(this).parent().parent().find('.appsList').height());
        if (actualHeight < 150) {
        $(".more").hide();  
        }
```

it hides all of the elements $(".more") instead of the ones that match the condition.

html as requested

```
<div class="appsHolder">

<div class="appsHolderBody">
<h5 class="appTitle">General Apps</h5>
<ul class="appsList">

<li class="mainAppList">Resource Manager</li>
<li><a href="">Launch</a> <a href="">Info</a></li>

<li class="mainAppList">Resource Manager</li>
<li><a href="">Launch</a> <a href="">Info</a></li>

<li class="mainAppList">Yet Another App</li>
<li><a href="">Launch</a> <a href="">Info</a></li>

<li class="mainAppList">Yet Another App</li>
<li><a href="">Launch</a> <a href="">Info</a></li>

<li class="mainAppList">Yet Another App</li>
<li><a href="">Launch</a> <a href="">Info</a></li>

<li class="mainAppList">Yet Another App</li>
<li><a href="">Launch</a> <a href="">Info</a></li>

<li class="mainAppList">Yet Another App</li>
<li><a href="">Launch</a> <a href="">Info</a></li>

<li class="mainAppList">Yet Another App</li>
<li><a href="">Launch</a> <a href="">Info</a></li>

</ul>
</div>

<div class="appsHolderExpander">
<a href="" class="more">More <img src="/wps/PA_applicationsintros/./img/downArrow.png" /></a>
<a href="" class="less">Less <img src="/wps/PA_applicationsintros/./img/upArrow.png" /></a>
</div>

</div>

<div class="appsHolderAdvertising">

<div class="appsHolderBody">
<h5 class="appTitle">Advertising Apps</h5>
<ul class="appsList">

<li class="mainAppList">ATEX</li>
<li><a href="">Launch</a> <a href="">Info</a></li>



</ul>
</div>

<div class="appsHolderExpander">
<a href="" class="more">More <img src="/wps/PA_applicationsintros/./img/downArrow.png" /></a>
<a href="" class="less">Less <img src="/wps/PA_applicationsintros/./img/upArrow.png" /></a>
</div>



</div>
```

cheers in advance

Comment: You can use the .parents([selector]) of jQuery to select a specific parent. There's also .closest([selector]) - check out the documentation, it explains both: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: cheers guys i will give that a whirl - however the problem is with cycling through the elements using the each() function and hiding $(".more")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still waiting for a reply on your comment but I refactored a little...

```
$(function() {
    $(".less").hide();
    $(".more").each(function() {
        if ($(this).parents('.appsList').height() < 150)
            $(this).hide();  
    });

    $(".more").click(function() {
        var paragraphHeight = $(this).parents('.appsList').height();
        if (paragraphHeight > 150) {
            $(this).parents('.appsHolderBody').animate({height:(paragraphHeight + 100)});
            $(this).hide('slow');
            $(this).parent().find('.less').show();
        }
        return false;    
    });

    $(".less").click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.appsHolderBody').animate({height:190 });
        $(this).hide('slow');
        $(this).parent().find('.more').show();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: cheers for the re factoring Hunter i have edited the main post to point out my problem a little more - if its not clear i will try again :) thanks for ur help

Comment: what is height() returning? have you debugged that or put in an alert?

Comment: height is returning fine - it returns the height of a list (ul) - the div then expands to match. this part all works fine its the part where i am trying to hide $(".more") for each element if it does not match the conditions.

Comment: I think if you post some HTML it will be more clear what is up.

Comment: if (actualHeight < 150) { $(this).hide(); }

Comment: the way it was will hide ALL $(".more") elements

Comment: from your html it doesn't look like .appsList is even a parent of .more

Comment: ok cool cheers - i think i missed some of the html off but yeh that works cheers hunter

Comment: i've added ur answer as the correct one as i could'nt tick the comment as the answer cheers

Answer (score 0):

Define a standard way of referencing the DIVs.  For example, place all the divs which follow this rule inside another DIV with ID="heightCheckingDivs".

Cycle through the DIVs in this collection and do what you are doing above. Add the class if needed, otherwise leave it alone. To make things easy on yourself, define a common class which holds the look-feel information and another two classes which apply the styles you need in the cases you are adding .more or .less